# Email notification for incorrect question

Tags: bug, subscription

I subscribe to new questions in the [roslyn](/questions/tagged/roslyn) tag.

I just got an email with the subject `New roslyn questions for Mar 16 - Stack Exchange` linking to the question [How to create a Pivot Chart (Excel 2013) with multiple query tables (CSV files) with dynamic data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821613/how-to-create-a-pivot-chart-excel-2013-with-multiple-query-tables-csv-files)

This question never had [roslyn](/questions/tagged/roslyn); the email says

> tagged: csv, pivot-table, excel-2013, multiple-files, pivot-chart

What kind of bug is this?

Comment: Likely a dupe of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345357/34397

Comment: sigh; I guess that means the error isn't where I thought (see dup); sorry!

Comment: @Marc yeah, good luck hunting down and fixing this bug!

Comment: @slaks can you please tell me: what time was this email sent?

Comment: @MarcGravell: `Mar 16, 2017, 1:58 AM`, EST

Comment: @slaks ah! That gives me some hope for my hypothesis, thanks - that was before I applied my duck-tape fix plus logging; I guess I'll turn it back on tomorrow and find out...

Comment: @MarcGravell: I assume you mean _duct_-tape :)

Comment: damn you autocorrect - although "duck" tape is not an uncommon phrasing and is actually a brand: https://www.amazon.co.uk/duck-tape/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aduck%20tape